# Add search method in phoenix REST controller and how to write the route?

Tags: routes, elixir, phoenix-framework

Phoenix framework generated RESTful controller is great, I am going to add method named `search` in the controller. The question is how to add url in `route.ex` to access the method? Now the route.ex looks like

scope "/api", RanksApi do
    pipe_through :api

```
scope "/v1", V1, as: :v1 do
  resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
end
```

end

Answer (score 2):

The quick answer in my mind is:

```
scope "/v1", V1, as: :v1 do
  get "/users/search", UserController, :search
  resources "/users", UserController, except: [:new, :edit]
end
```

`get "/users/search", UserController, :search` must before `users` RESTful routes

Comment: Yes that's right. If you define the search route after the RESTful routes, it will be ignored and the "search" in `/users/search` will be interpreted as ID.